# What's the difference between declaring variables inside function and outside functions

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, global-variables, variable-declaration

What are ***all*** the major practical differences between [1] and [2]?

[1] (I know if you declare outside the function you can use the variable in multiple functions):

```
var myNumber:Number = 42;

function functionOne():void
{
    trace(myNumber);
    return;
}
function functionTwo():void
{
    trace(myNumber);
    return;
}
```

[2]:

```
function functionOne():void
{
    var myNumber:Number = 42;
    trace(myNumber);
    return;
}
```

**Some specific questions:**

~ What happens to the variable when a function containing a variable declaration is called multiple times?

~ Are there any differences in performance between [1] and [2]?

~ Are there any more differences to variable declarations inside loops or condition statements?

(both (here) and {here})

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html see the section on variable scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the scope of the variable, 
as suggested by Karma inside comments, you will found what you're searching for here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html

To be more specific :

> ~ What happens to the variable when a function containing a variable
>   declaration is called multiple times?

each function call will have a proper stack, so you will create another variable each time you call the same function.

> ~ Are there any differences in performance between [1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html) and [2]?

I'm not sure, but i think this is not an issue. The real difference is in your code readability and it allows a function to interact with another one by this variable which may not be what you want.

> ~ Are there any more differences to variable declarations inside loops
>   or condition statements?
>
> (both (here) and {here})

Same here, the difference is the scope, when you declare a variable, it can only be accessed inside its scope.

Comment: On performance...In general there is no performance difference between a "class" and a "function" variable.

There are some factors that can cause issues. The number of variables and the size of the variables. These both have to do with the amount of memory used.

For instance, if you have a variable that is an Array of 1000 objects that are each 1MB in size. There is a big difference between having this scoped to a function or a class variable. The function variable would be garbage collected (potential) much sooner and free memory. Unless the function is called many times each second.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference in performance under certain conditions as hinted by C. Parcell.

Think of a rendering engine. If you would create a new variable in every frame it won't be too bad, but what if that frame needs to call your function tens of thousands times? Then you will accumulate a lot of variables until the garbage collector finally kicks in. And the GC doesn't run on every frame because that would bring your app to a grinding halt.

And, with that many repetitions, the creation of a variable takes more time than to assign something to it. In general, if you are after performance, it is pretty useful to scope as many vars as possible to the class if you (in whatever way) plan to use them in lengthy/heavy loops. In some cases, though, you might actually *want* to create a new variable in a loop, so keep that in mind when scoping/debugging.

Same principle as storing functions from other classes in a `const` of your own class, like so `internal static const abs:Function = Math.abs;`. The performance difference is marginal, but with enough repetitions it does have an effect. Essentially this creates a 'copy' of the function during compiling, so that the necessary look up to execute the command is one step shorter (`abs` instead of `Math` and then `abs`).